# How can I resolve this Anaconda launch problem?

Tags: 20.04, anaconda

When I launch anaconda in Ubuntu using  'anaconda-navigator' the screen has a glitchy window:

[image: The Glitch when Opening Anaconda]

Anaconda launches after about 5 min. I have tried reinstalling multiple times but the problem persists. The glitchy window remains overtop other application windows as well.

| System | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Ubuntu Desktop | 20.04.3 LTS |
| Anaconda | Anaconda3-2021.05 |

Answer (score 1):

Experience has shown this to be an issue with the SSL Verification feature of the application. There are a few things you can do here:

0. Ensure Anaconda is closed
1. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
2. Check the settings:

   ```
   conda config --show
   ```
3. Disable the SSL Verification:

   ```
   conda config --set ssl_verify false
   ```
4. Launch Anaconda ... and let it take its time
5. Go to "Preferences" and ensure "Enable SSL Verification" is disabled
6. Press "Apply"

This should result in a much faster loading Anaconda installation. The glitchy window will probably still exist, but will disappear after a split second.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . But the problem didn't get solved.